# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 | python install packages

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, server

I trying to install pip3 packages for the python3.6 project in EC2 manually.

I run this command in my flask project directory

```
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

It returns the error:

```
Collecting kappa==0.6.0
  Using cached kappa-0.6.0.tar.gz (29 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python36 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ipujjrys/kappa/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ipujjrys/kappa/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-ipujjrys/kappa/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ipujjrys/kappa/
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ipujjrys/kappa/setup.py", line 54, in <module>
        run_setup()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ipujjrys/kappa/setup.py", line 22, in run_setup
        long_description=open_file('README.rst').read(),
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2339: ordinal not in range(128)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

what could be the possible solution?

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm guessing it's one that doesn't have 'utf-8' as its default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to manually set your EC2 system locale to `utf-8` before installing the package, since it is not natively supported.

**The Solution:**

If you want to change or set system local, use the `update-locale` program. The `LANG` variable allows you to set the locale for the entire system.

The following command sets `LANG` to `en_IN.UTF-8` and removes definitions for `LANGUAGE`.

```
sudo update-locale LANG=LANG=en_IN.UTF-8 LANGUAGE
```